# Parametrization of KSS-16 curves, choosing a prime and understand the Ate pairing field size.

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

I'm actually really confused. I just looked it up in different sources [1,2,3a] [1] states

$q=1/980(u^{10} + 2u^9 + 5u^8 + 48u^6 + 152u^5 + 240u^4 + 625u^2 + 2398u + 3125)$

where $q=p^d$ for any prime $p$ and integer $d$. The other both sources states this with $p$ and names it the field size.

There is the first part I cannot follow directly. <strike>But the next thing is also weird: in [3b] there is a new key size recommendation for 128 bit of equivalent security. It is a 34-bit "prime":</strike>

$u = -2^{34} +2^{27} -2^{23} +2^{20} - 2^{11} +1$ or a 35-bit $u=2^{35} - 2^{32} -2^{18} + 2^{8} +1$

but, if I let Sage check, it turnes out, that none of them is a prime.

If I, furthermore, consider the optimal Ate pairing, it will get into $\mathbb F_{p^k}$, and if I plug in that 34-bit "prime" it leads to a field size of <strike>545</strike> 5441 bits, what is quite to low?

Could someone help me get light in that fog?

## References

[1] Mrabet etal. Guide to Pairing-Based Cryptography. 2017. Page 4-14. Example 4.5

[2] https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/472 , page 3 section 2.1

[3] https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/334 ,

- (a) page 4 section 2.3
- (b) page 13 section 6.3

Comment: If you plug the $u's$ into the above formula, you actually get two primes. And the primes are big enough for cryptographical purposes.

Comment: Are you sure? I plugged this into sage, let sage calculate everything and did a prime-check, it returned: false. How did you check this? I just used the formulae and did p.is_prime() in Sage. And just for be sure: you get a prime equivalent to 13 mod 32? Just for checking, this is what I get: 615623382030675150502066218751443438064107566348210118507940234835256709422634902533028653925239565581 


Wolframalpha says: prime. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+615623382030675150502066218751443438064107566348210118507940234835256709422634902533028653925239565581+prime%3F

Comment: I guess that Sage uses a probability test, and this fails here.

Comment: I used PARI and proved the primality with the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely-method. SAGE should manage this as well, check for possible typos in the input.

Comment: Ok. I trust in your correctnes. Thank you for that hint! The first thing is then done, therefore.

Comment: I repeated my calculation (to rule out input-errors) and again got that both numbers are prime : $$21221701344886867791100$$ $$652850982014911111393711817963402400071851758703670191428
86063847799313988109$$ and $$6156233820306751505020662187514434380641075663482101185079402348352567094226$$ $$3490
2533028653925239565581$$

Comment: If $q$ is a prime power, there exists a field with $q$ elements, therefore $q$ is the "field size". Is $p$ in the other sources a prime power or a prime ?

Comment: It looks like a prime.  They are not that precise. [2] says explicit "p prime" and [3] uses "q" and "p" in the introduction. It seems like, they use $p$ as a prime.